# Golang segmentio/kafka-go consumer not working

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using [segmentio/kafka-go](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go) to connect to Kafka.

```
// to produce messages
topic := "my-topic"
partition := 0

conn, _ := kafka.DialLeader(context.Background(), "tcp", "localhost:9092", topic, partition)

conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(10*time.Second))
conn.WriteMessages(
    kafka.Message{Value: []byte("one!")},
    kafka.Message{Value: []byte("two!")},
    kafka.Message{Value: []byte("three!")},
)

conn.Close()
```

I am able to produce into my Kafka server using this code.

```
// to consume messages
topic := "my-topic"
partition := 0

conn, _ := kafka.DialLeader(context.Background(), "tcp", "localhost:9092", topic, partition)

conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(10*time.Second))
batch := conn.ReadBatch(10e3, 1e6) // fetch 10KB min, 1MB max

b := make([]byte, 10e3) // 10KB max per message
for {
    _, err := batch.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        // err -> "invalid codec"
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

batch.Close()
conn.Close()
```

But I am unable to consume using the above code. I am getting the error `invalid codec`. What can be the reason?

In case relevant, I tweaked the minimum batch size to 1 so that it tries to consume something.

Comment: Are you able to consume with the console consumer?

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess:
try adding an import to load compression codecs, in case your topics use compression.

import _ "github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/snappy"